# How does one let a code run after certain amount of time in java

Tags: java, android

```
    @Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    //Drawing the background and sprites as it is a blackboard.
    canvas.drawBitmap(scaledbmp, 0, 0, null);
    sprite.onDraw(canvas);
    boolean new_missle = true;
    missileStartTime = System.nanoTime();

    for (int i = missleslist.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if (new_missle) {
            missleslist.get(i).onDraw(canvas);
            new_missle = false;
        }
        if (!new_missle && (missileStartTime - System.nanoTime()) == 1000000){
            new_missle = true;
            missileStartTime = System.nanoTime();
        }
    }
}
```

Hello there, i posted my code first. What i'm trying to do here is drawing missles on a board, but not drawing them all at the same time and draw them seperatly after x milli/micro seconds. Anyhow this code does not work and i don't see why.

Kees

Comment: i have never used this platform...but can't you sleep your program for x seconds and draw when it wakes...then again sleep and then again wake and so on...

Comment: you're almost never going to get an an exactly 1,000,000 nanosecond difference. there will ALWAYS be some variation in runtimes of each loop iteration, and you'll go from 999,999 -> 1,000,001 and never trigger the if(), because you didn't hit that one magical time difference. it should be `>=`, not `==`.

Comment: What does not work? Could you provide some details? Please check also your conditions of the second if-statement: is the == operator the right one to use?

Comment: change it to `>=` 1000000 instead of `==`

Comment: @StefanFreitag This program is supposed to draw sprites from an arraylist, but wait an amount of time before it can draw the next element in the list. Now it only draws one and it's supposed to draw three with a time interval of let's say 3

Comment: i think it's not working because it skipps the statement (!new_missle && (missileStartTime - System.nanoTime()) >= 1000000)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your condition is wrong, you expect your nanotime to be exactly equals to '1000000' when it reaches this portion of code, which would be quite lucky to get. You should use >=

And are you sure about the way your loop should work ? You can't control how fast it'll loop (well, not like that, and it shouldn't be your goal), and here for each loop you're losing a possible fired missile. Might for example start with something like :

```
//as long as you have missiles, it'll try to fire
while(missleslist.size() > 0) {
    if (System.nanoTime() - missileStartTime  >= 1000000){
        missleslist.get(0).onDraw(canvas);
        missleslist.remove(0);
        missileStartTime = System.nanoTime();
    }
}
```

Comment: yeah i was thinking the same, the loop did not work indeed..... i'll try this one :)

Comment: There was a typo, but it should instead be 
System.nanoTime() - missileStartTime
As the actual time will be greater than the old one, fixing the infinite loop

Comment: hmmmmm, i have exactly the same problem: the missles won't fire

Answer (score 1):

As others have pointed out some of the existing problems in your existing code, I won't rehash them here.

Because you have tagged [android-studio](/questions/tagged/android-studio) (incorrectly) in your question and because you are using `View#onDraw(Canvas)`, I assume you are talking about Android.

You should use the [Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) class of Android, particularly the `Handler#postDelayed(int)` method to delay code to be executed at a later time:

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    //Drawing the background and sprites as it is a blackboard.
    canvas.drawBitmap(scaledbmp, 0, 0, null);
    sprite.onDraw(canvas);

    startDrawingMissiles(canvas, missileList, 0);
}

private void startDrawingMissiles(Canvas canvas, List<Missiles> missileList, 
                                  int currentIndex) {

    if (currentIndex < missileList.size()) {
        Handler handler = new Handler(); 
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() { 
            public void run() { 
                missileList.get(currentIndex).onDraw(canvas);
                startDrawingMissiles(canvas, missileList, ++currentIndex);
            } 
        }, 1000000); // <- Your duration 
    }
}
```

There might be some subtle issues with the code above, but it illustrates what you're trying to achieve.